# How do I test methods of React components and include them in my Istanbul coverage?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, testing

I was wondering how I'm able to test the methods of my react components and include them in my Istanbul test coverage?

Edit: I'm using enzyme. Forgot to mention that.

For example, I have this component:

```
class SearchFormContainer extends Component {
  static handleToggle = () => {
    const filter = document.querySelector('.filter-container');
    const root = document.getElementById('root');
    if (filter.classList.contains('closed')) {
      filter.classList.remove('closed');
      filter.classList.add('opened');
      root.classList.add('paused');
    } else {
      root.classList.remove('paused');
      filter.classList.remove('opened');
      filter.classList.add('closed');
    }
  };

  updateQuantity = (e) => {
    const { store } = this.props;
    store.setQuantity(e.target.value);
  }

  updateStrength = (e) => {
    const { store } = this.props;
    store.setStrength(e.target.value);
  }

  updateCustomQuantity = (e) => {
    const { store } = this.props;
    let value = e.target.value || '';
    if (!value) {
      store.setPricingError('invalidquantity');
    } else {
      value = value.match(/\d+(\.)?(\d+)?/);

      if (!value) {
        value = '';
      } else {
        value = value[0];
      }

      if (parseFloat(value) <= 0) {
        store.setPricingError('invalidquantity');
      } else if (store.pricingError === 'invalidquantity') {
        store.setPricingError(null);
      }
    }

    store.setCustomQuantity(value);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      styleName,
      openFilterLabel,
      closeFilterLabel,
      updateFilterLabel,
      searchLabel,
      quantityLabel,
      strengthLabel,
      zipLabel,
      zipPlaceholder,
      searchFormAnchor,
      customQuantityPlaceholder,
      store,
      searchBar,
    } = this.props;
    const toggled = 'closed';
    const { useCustomQuantity } = store;

    let inputType = 'predefined';

    if (useCustomQuantity) {
      inputType = 'custom';
    } else {
      inputType = 'predefined';
    }

    const handleCustomInput = () => {
      store.toggleUseCustomQuantity();
    };
```

Here's a test I'm trying to run (note that I've assigned store and searchBar in the describe block.

```
  it('calls upDateQuantity', () => {
    sinon.spy(App.prototype, 'updateQuantity');
    const updateQuantity = sinon.stub();
    const component = shallow(<App
      updateQuantity={updateQuantity}
      store={store}
      searchBar={searchBar}
      openFilterLabel="Filter"
      closeFilterLabel="Close"
      updateFilterLabel="UPDATE"
      searchLabel="Medication Name"
      quantityLabel="Quantity"
      strengthLabel="Strength"
      zipLabel="ZIP code"
      zipPlaceholder="11111"
      searchFormAnchor="SearchForm"
      name="search-field"
      placeholder="Search drug name..."
      customQuantityPlaceholder="Enter Custom Quantity"
    />);
    component.find('#quantitySelector').simulate('click');
    expect(App.updateQuantity.callCount).to.equal(1);
 });
```

I'm not sure if this will even test the actual function, seems like it will just test to see if the event was fired? I'm getting the error:

`TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property updateQuantity as function.`

I'm not sure how to test certain methods above, such as handleToggle, updateQuantity, UpdateStrength, etc. My react testing skills are young, so any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) to render the react component within your test and proceed as follow. You can then test your component methods directly with:

```
const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />)
component.instance().myMethod()
```

Or if you need to trigger an event on your component, you can do as follow:

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import ButtonControl from '../ButtonControl'

describe('ButtonControl component', () => {
  it('handleClick', () => {

    let onClickHandler = jest.fn()
    let props = { handleClick: onClickHandler }

    let component = shallow(<ButtonControl {...props} />)

    component.find('button').first().props().onClick()
    expect(onClickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

this test use jest plus code coverage. Enzyme is compatible with jasmine, it should be easy to adapt.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My methods are not in the instance, perhaps because I used arrow functions? Any ideas on how I might access them?

Comment: The arrow functions should not be a problem here, for the static function, this is another story. What version of enzyme are you using?

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 2.8.2. If i console.log component.instance().updateQuantity, I get undefined?

Comment: Is it possible to add the code of your test so that we can have more info on what's going wrong, eg are you using `shallow`, `mount` or `render`?

Comment: Absolutely, just edited my question to include a test I'm trying out. Like I said above, not sure that this will actually test the function and include it in my coverage, which is the goal. Again, thanks very much for the responses!

Comment: You want to test `App` component or `SearchFormContainer`? The test is testing `App`. On top of that, if you want to test nested components, you should not use `shallow` but `mount` or `render` instead. Why not testing `SearchFormContainer` directly?